# Removing the TinyMCE editor for a given page template

Tags: pages, wp-admin, page-template, tinymce

I was looking for a way to remove the TinyMCE Editor for a specific page template in a theme (in my case it's page-home.php). I found the following code, which works, however, I was wondering if this could be accomplished in a better/neater way, perhaps using some of WordPress' built-in functions for finding the ID of the page...

```
function hide_editor() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($template_file == 'page-home.php'){ // template name here
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code but that looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hook on `load-page` hook instead of `admin_init`. It is supposed to be called only when a page is being edited, and then you should be able to use the global `$post` variable

```
function hide_editor() {
   global $post;

    $template_file = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($template_file == 'page-home.php'){ // template name here
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
add_action( 'load-page', 'hide_editor' );
```

Comment: I finally got the time to test out your code. It doesn't seem to work unfortunately...

Comment: It doesn't work. In order to make it work you have to use the hook `admin_init`. Unfortunally doing this the text editor also disappears :/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function hide_editor() {
  if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])){
    $post_id = $_REQUEST['post'];
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($template_file == 'page-home.php'){ // template name here
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'hide_editor' );
```